# How to find a Forum or a Node by passing a JWT Token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

I would like to know how I can find my forum using my JWT token

```
exports.getByOwnerID = function (req, res, next) {
  Forum.find({createdBy: req.body.createdBy})
  .then(doc => {
      if(!doc) { return res.status(400).end();}
      return res.status(200).json(doc);
  })
  .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

So here I have my function to verify my JWT Token
I use it for example this way

this is my route :
router.post('/',verifyToken,getOwner);

this is my request :
POST http://localhost:8080/forum/getOwner
Authorization: Bearer {token}

```
const extractToken = (rawTokenHeader) => {
  
  if(!rawTokenHeader) { return undefined; }

  // Remove bearer and extract token value
  const temp = rawTokenHeader.split(' ');
  if(!temp || temp.length != 2) { return undefined; }

  // Return encoded token
  return temp[1];

};

module.exports = function(req,res,next){
  // Get authorization header
  const rawTokenHeader = req.header('Authorization');

  // Get token value
  const token = extractToken(rawTokenHeader);

  // No token -> No access
  if(!token) {
    console.log('No token in request');
    // Access denied
    return res.status(401).send('Access Denied');
  }
  
  // Verify token
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);

    req.token= decoded;
    req.user = decoded;
    //console.log(token.userID);
        // Proceed
    next();
  } catch(err) {
    console.error('Error in JWT check: ', err);
    // Tell client something went wrong
    res.status(400).send('Invalid Token');
  }
}
```

```
const forumSchema = ({
    forumName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    forumDescription: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    createdBy: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' 
    },
    published_on: {
        type: String,
        default: moment().format("LLL")
    },
});
```

I´ve tried a lot of things but I can´t solve it anymore.. I need help

Comment: Your question mentions JWT, but the code does not include any JSON Web Token-related instructions. Do you have JWT implemented? Is it being passed to the server? If so, in what form - a cookie, a header? Do you have a middleware that decodes the JWT?

Comment: Yes wait I will put it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I don't have enough reputation to make a comment I leave this as an answer, is hard to say why this is not working if we don't know how the schema of Forum looks like and what is returning req.body.createdBy, but if the jwt is created by you could encode the Forum._id in it and when you receive it here you can decode it and find the forum in the database

edit---

Now that I can see the error you got and the Schema of Forum i can say that probably you can solve the error by importing mongoose and adding this at the query `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.CreatedBy)` that will parse the string to an objectId

Comment: Can you write this as a code ? I can also add the schema of Forum

Comment: i hope the edit works @Deezer

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you have `user` (or `token`) data in the `req` object, and I hope your jwt token also includes the user's id. You can use the user id to find their Forums.

According to the router `router.post('/', verifyToken, getOwner);` (`getByOwnerID` ???), let's update `getOwner` handler:

```
exports.getOwner = function (req, res, next) {
  Forum.find({ createdBy: req.user.userID }) // or something like that
  .then(doc => {
      if(!doc) { return res.status(400).end();}
      return res.status(200).json(doc);
  })
  .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

Comment: it includes userID yes but Here I can´t find any post from admin..
the message is: Cas to ObjectId failed for value "admin" (type string) at path "createdBy" for model "Forum"